# Polylang language recognition not working from social network

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I have created a multilingual website using WordPress and Polylang. I have set English as the primary language for my WordPress site with Polylang, and I have also prepared the translation in Italian. I have enabled the function to detect the user's language: if an Italian user visits, they should be directed to the Italian version of the site.

When I access the site by typing the link in the browser, everything works correctly. However, if I put the link in the bio of Facebook or Instagram and click on it, I always end up on the English version of the site.

How can I solve this issue?